# MySQL return 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated query that returns a percentage but I need to have it return only 2 decimal places. I have searched the forums and trues truncate, round, cast, decimal, and a few others I am sure I am missing. I am at a complete loss as to where to go from here. The query is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code

```
SELECT branch, SUM( monthly_total / ( 
   SELECT SUM(hour1) 
   FROM `door_count` 
   WHERE `numeric_month` <= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
   AND fy = 2013
   AND numeric_month <> '0'
   AND branch = 'Main St.'
  ) *100 
) 
FROM door_count
WHERE fy = 2014
AND branch = 'Main St.';
```

Comment: `ROUND(foo, 2)`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round  Why are you searching through forums when the official manual is available, and the function name is blindingly obvious?

Comment: do you want 2 decimals, always?

Comment: Man, that is one complicated query...

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROUND() function:

```
SELECT branch, ROUND(SUM( monthly_total / ( 
   SELECT SUM(hour1) 
   FROM `door_count` 
   WHERE `numeric_month` <= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
   AND fy = 2013
   AND numeric_month <> '0'
   AND branch = 'Main St.'
  ) *100 
), 2) 
FROM door_count
WHERE fy = 2014
AND branch = 'Main St.';
```